# how to add button value from tag a title on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on my real-estate project, I have a contact modal box and I want to get the title from tag a into the button value in modal box.

I'm not good at English, if I'm saying something wrong somewhere please forgive me

I have tried many ways but it still doesn't work and the result I get is the title but only works just for 1 id

```js
  function change() {
        let a_id = document.getElementById('test');
        let btn_id = document.getElementById("btn-test");

        let btn = a_id.getAttributeNode('title').value;
    
        // btn_id.value = btn;

        btn_id.innerHTML = btn_id.value = btn;
  
   }
```

```html
<body>

    <p>Click the button find out if the button has an onclick attribute specified.</p>
    <a href="#" title="bye" id="test">hello</a>
    <input type="button" onload="change()" title="hello" value="Try it" id="btn-test">
  </body>
```

this is my code https://hastebin.com/ohasiqavun.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the following alternative for you to get the values from every button seperate. noticed that I changed the HTML to 3 container who all include the same content. I removed the ID's and changed them for classes:

JS:

```
let changeallbuttons = document.querySelector('.changeallbuttons')
  changeallbuttons.addEventListener('click', function() {
   document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(item =>{
    let button = item.querySelector('input')
    let a = item.querySelector('.test')

    button.value   = a.getAttribute('title')
   })
  })
 document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(item =>{
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
   let button = item.querySelector('input')
   let a = item.querySelector('.test')

   button.value   = a.getAttribute('title')
  })
 })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Click the button find out if the button has an onclick attribute specified.</p>
    <a href="#" title="bye1" class="test" >hello</a>
    <input type="button" title="hello" value="Try it">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Click the button find out if the button has an onclick attribute specified.</p>
    <a href="#" title="bye2" class="test" >hello</a>
    <input type="button" title="hello" value="Try it">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Click the button find out if the button has an onclick attribute specified.</p>
    <a href="#" title="bye3" class="test">hello</a>
    <input type="button" title="hello" value="Try it">
  </div>
  <input class="changeallbuttons" type="button" title="hello" value="Try it">
```

Comment: i have a question i want to use the event from "click" to "load" how can i that because i want when i click a button there will be a modal box appear and inside modal box have another button and button value have the title value

Comment: Sorry, Are you able to explain this a little bit more?

Comment: i just want 1 event click on 1 button for example if i click button the modal box will open and your code will run

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cuoiduyenne/5beqa0o8/64/ like this if i have tag input in another place how can i run the code

Comment: Can you explain on that fiddle which classes or elements you want to open when clicking on which item? Please be more specific

Comment: I think your HTML in the fiddle doesn't make sense. I've added the button to change all the values of all buttons on 1 click. The buttons can also be clicked seperate as well with the code I changed in my solution above ( EDITED )

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use classes instead of ids here. Ids are unique and thus it only works for 1 element.